# Testing for association on categorical data, have I done it right?

Tags: r, categories

I want to test if there is an association between the number of rodents that survive a virus (made up) with or without a vaccine. This is my data:

```
Treatment   Number of deaths    Number of Survivors
Vaccinated                11                     36
not vaccinated            24                     26
```

And below how I input it into R:

```
dframe1 <- read.csv(file.choose())
names(dframe1)
# [1] "Treatment"           "Number.of.deaths"    "Number.of.survivors"
count <- table (dframe1$Number.of.deaths, dframe1$Number.of.survivors) 
count
#    26 36
# 11  0  1
# 24  1  0
chisq.test(count)
#      Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
# 
# data:  count
# X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1

# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(count) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Have I done this correctly?

If not, then please help. 
Cheers.

Comment: your count table seems very wrong. so the answer to your question is probably no.

Comment: If you know what I have done wrong, then please would you be so kind as to help me? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the values of interest to be inside the table, rather than as row and column names like so:

```
count <- data.frame(dframe1$Number.of.deaths, dframe1$Number.of.survivors)
```

When you run your chi-square test of association you should now get the following output:

```
chisq.test(count)

# Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
# data:  count
# X-squared = 5.3331, df = 1, p-value = 0.02092
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) However I get this error..Error in chisq.test(count) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

Comment: Can you post what your count data frame looks like?

Alternatively, you can just create your count data frame by hand:

count <- data.frame(c(11,24),c(36,26))

Comment: > count
  dframe1.Number.of.deaths dframe1.Number.of.survivors
1                       NA                          NA
2                       11                          36
3                       24                          26

Comment: The problem is the NAs in the data frame. Copy my line of code that created count exactly and you shouldn't end up with NAs.

Comment: I did. There was an extra row in the excel file which I have removed and I do not gets the NAs. It works now, but I get slightly different answers: > count
  dframe1.Number.of.deaths dframe1.Number.of.survivors
1                       11                          36
2                       24                          26
> chisq.test(count)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  count
X-squared = 5.3331, df = 1, p-value = 0.02092 Thank you for the help though so far you have been really kind.

Comment: I get what you get. Because I had to create the data myself, I had a typo in count (25 instead of 26).